# Does caching remote resources in Eclipse have an impact on performance?

Tags: eclipse, caching, resources

Frequently I see this in progress. What does it mean? Is it needed for eclipse work or it is like advertisement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse uses a virtual filesystem under the hood for all resources. This filesystem management has some common mechanism to make an access possible through a single interface so that you can use all the features for accessing and manipulating resources no matter if they are local or remote (your Navigator-View for instance has no idea about local or remote resources..).

This "common interface" holds some meta-information about the file and folder structure of all projects (local or remote or whatever). For updating/creating these meta-information Eclipse index these files. This is no cache of the entire file, only meta-information of all files are collected.
So to your questions:

> Does eclipse caching remote resources

No it doesn't. It only builds several indexes of meta-information for **all** files (so that you can use for instance the ctrl+shirt+r dialog)

> Does it need for eclipse work

Yes it does. This is an essential mechanism for Eclipse which is also needed for the incremental [Builder-Infrastructure](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html).

Answer (score 1):

Caching resources is what allows you to quickly open any given class or resources using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcuts

Comment: Not sure. Why REMOTE resources?